# How to edit the NetworkManager connections while not live

Tags: network-manager

I have the hard drive of another machine mounted on my current machine as a drive.

I can navigate through the disk and open/close/edit files.

nmcli appears to only work on a live machine.

How do I edit the wifi connection on this drive, such that when I put it back into the original machine it runs from it will connect as usual.

Notes:

- Other machine is headless (no monitor), but has desktop installed to
  run VMs
- I changed my wifi password
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu server? `lsb_release -d` If the machine runs headless, Network Manager is not running.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Server 16.04, running headless, that is, with no running desktop environment, Network Manager will not be running and will therefore not be the location of network settings.

I suggest that you edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to change the WPA2 password. The file will probably read something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <your_router>
wpa-psk <your_old_wpa_key>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Change the password, save and close the text editor and you should be all set.

Comment: I updated the Q per your answer. I'm thinking that I'm going to have to grab an extra monitor and set it up this way instead of using the network manager.

Comment: May I please reiterate: "In Ubuntu Server 16.04, running headless, that is, with no running desktop environment, Network Manager will not be running and will therefore not be the location of network settings."